# R - aggregating sum row wise

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame mydf as  `mydf <- data.frame(month = c('apr', 'may', 'june'),cost = c(100, 150, 200))`

I wish to get a runningTotal that sums each record cumulatively

```
  month cost runningTotal
1   apr  100          100
2   may  150          250
3  june  200          450
```

I tried using dplyr sum but didn't work.
Can someone help me find the most efficient way of doing this
Thanks.

Comment: `mydf$runningTotal=cumsum(mydf$cost)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf%>%
   mutate(runningTotal = cumsum(cost))
```

Comment: Why downvoting again ??

Comment: It's pathetic ...thank you for help anyway